# Did indigenous permanent members within the Arctic Council ever complain about a lack of authority or influence?

Tags: international, arctic

> Permanent Participants may address the meetings. They may raise points
> of order that require an immediate decision by the chairman. Agendas
> of Ministerial Meetings need to be consulted beforehand with them;
> they may propose supplementary agenda items. When calling the biannual
> meetings of Senior Arctic Officials, the Permanent Participants must
> have been consulted beforehand. **Moreover, though only states have a
> right to vote in the Arctic Council, the permanent participants must,
> according to the Ottawa Declaration be fully consulted, which is close
> to de facto power of veto should they all reject a particular**
> proposal.[16] This mandatory consultation process matches the
> consultation and « free, prior and informed consent » (FPIC)
> requirement mentioned in the United Nation Declaration on the Rights
> of Indigenous Peoples. Finally, Permanent Participants may propose
> cooperative activities, such as projects. All this makes the position
> of Arctic indigenous peoples within the Arctic Council quite
> influential compared to the (often marginal) role of such peoples in
> other international governmental fora. The status of "permanent
> participant" is indeed unique and enables circumpolar peoples to be
> seated at the same table as states' delegations while in any other
> international organization it is not the case. Nevertheless,
> decision-making in the Arctic Council remains in the hands of the
> eight-member states, on the basis of consensus.[citation needed]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_Council

Looking at the rights they have, which is a permanent "veto" power, it could be argued that they have the most power within the organization, but at the same time, they can't vote like member states can, so I was wondering if any of the indigenous permanent members ever complain about a lack of authority or influence within the Arctic Council, or whether they demanded more power, such as the ability to cast votes.

Comment: I suspect that their veto right is similar to the British King’s: can only be used once, after which they’d be kicked off the council. Complaining would likewise increase the risk of them just being kicked out entirely.